# How to do this IF with ternary operators

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

how can I do this IF with ternary operators?

```
if (img != null) {
  return img;
} else if (!user) {
  return 'img.svg';
} else if (user) {
  if (user.img && !camera) {
    return `imgServer`;
  } else if (!user.img && !camera) {
    return 'img.svg';
  } else if (user.img && camera) {
    return camera;
  } else if (!user.img && camera) {
    return camera;
  }
}
```

I already tried it in several ways, but none of them work for me.

Comment: Your `else if (user)` can be simplified to just `else` (as the prior condition was `!user`, therefore `else if(user)` and `else` are equivalent), unless there's some non-exclusive falsyness going on.

Comment: Apart from the one unnecessary `else if` noted above, I think your current code is fine.

Comment: As you return in every branch, you don't need any `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you need a ternary here? Personally, I've always found ternaries to be difficult to grok and debug at the best of times.

---

I would start by simplifying your if statement tree. As others have said, you can simplify the `else if (user)` to `else. Giving you:

```js
if (img != null) {
  return img;
} else if (!user) {
  return 'img.svg';
} else {
  // simplified because of the previous if statement
  if (user.img && !camera) {
    return `imgServer`;
  } else if (!user.img && !camera) {
    return 'img.svg';
  } else if (user.img && camera) {
    return camera;
  } else if (!user.img && camera) {
    return camera;
  }
}
```

Then I would tackle making the nested if statement simpler by re-ordering it:

```js
if (img != null) {
  return img;
} else if (!user) {
  return 'img.svg';
} else {
  // simplified because of the previous if statement
  if (user.img && !camera) {
    return `imgServer`;
  } else if (!user.img && camera) {
    return camera;
  } else if (user.img && camera) {
    return camera;
  }
  // Since there are four possible states allowed
  // (write out a truth table for proof), we can
  // simplify this nested if statement
  return 'img.svg';
}
```

Now that everything is simplified, you can tackle creating a ternary. First, the nested if:

```js
if (img != null) {
  return img;
} else if (!user) {
  return 'img.svg';
} else {
  // simplified because of the previous if statement
  return (user.img && !camera) ? `imgServer` :
         (!user.img && camera) ? camera : 
         (user.img && camera) ? camera :
         'img.svg';
}
```

And finally the outer if statement:

```js
return (img != null) ? img :
       (!user) ? 'img.svg' :
         (user.img && !camera) ? `imgServer` :
         (!user.img && camera) ? camera : 
         (user.img && camera) ? camera :
         'img.svg';
}
```

Comment: You're the first person who actually answered the question that was asked (substitute a nested ternary expression for "if/else" blocks)

Comment: I didn't think it was that easy! This worked for me. Thank you very much partner! And everyone for their answers !!

Answer (score 5):

You could compress the statements into this without using an unradable and understandable ternary.

```
if (img != null) return img;            // maybe this would work, too if (img) return img;
if (!user || !user.img) return 'img.svg';
if (camera) return camera;
return `imgServer`;
```

An even shorter approach:

```
return image
    || (!user || !user.img) && 'img.svg'
    || camera
    || `imgServer`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a couple if statements..

```
const imgSvg = 'img.svg' // Maybe use a variable for 'img.svg'?

if (img) return img
if (!user) return imgSvg
return camera || (user.img ? 'imgServer' : imgSvg)
```

So..

If you have `img`, just return it.

If you don't have `img`.. then the next thing to do is return 'img.svg' if there is no `user` present..

ie.. `if (!user) return imgSvg`

From there it depends on `camera`, and `user.img`..

ie.. `return camera || user.img ? 'imgServer' : imgSvg`

Note: this is very similar to @Nina Scholz answer.. but you have a case where:

if `!user.img` and `camera` is present, return `camera`

@Nina Scholz [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65028466/9808057) doesn't allow for that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `return` statements in your `if`s, your code might need a little bit of remodelling...
This is a *direct equivalence* from what you wrote above.

```js
let returnValue = img != null ? img : !user ? 'img.svg' : user.img && !camera ? `imgServer` : !user.img && !camera ? 'img.svg' : user.img && camera ? camera : !user.img && camera : camera;
return returnValue;
```

But to be honest, I feel like this specific example could be a little bit simplifed...

> As pointed out in the comments, since you have `return` statements, you don't need all those `else if` and you can compress your logic a bit

The following would be equivalent to the code in your question

```js
if (img != null) return img;
if (!user) return 'img.svg';
if (!camera) {
  if (user.img) return `imgServer`;
return 'img.svg';
}
return camera;
```

And *if* you absolutely want that in ternary, that'd be:

```js
let returnValue = img != null ? img : !user ? 'img.svg' : !camera ? user.img ? `imgServer` : 'img.svg' : camera;
return returnValue;
```

This would be a less compact and maybe not as eleguant answer than the one Nina Scholz did, but if the sequence of `if`s and boolean evaluation matter to you, it might do the trick